# PhoneGap onDeviceReady won't fire up on iPhone

Tags: cordova

I've got a PhoneGap app that won't run the "deviceready" event on an iPhone but WILL run it on Android.

Any ideas why is this? or how to fix it?

(PhoneGap ver 1.0)

The code is :

```
function onBodyLoad()
{
     if (typeof navigator.device == "undefined"){
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
     } else {
         onDeviceReady();
     }
}

<body onload="onBodyLoad()">
```

Thanks!

Comment: OK. Found it - the PhoneGap framework didn't fire up because of a compiler thingy. the jQuery part did fire and thus the app seemed fine, but all the PhoneGap part didn't and thus I couldn't use the deviceready.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you just copy your www folder from one to the other? Android and iOS use their own phonegap-1.0.0.js file. Make sure you are using the correct js file for the platform.

Comment: you were right! I used the JS from android for the iPhone. That DIDN'T work :)

Comment: Wasn't obvious for me as well.

Comment: Boos thanks...u solved my problem i had wasted lots of my time but your post save my time that i could west due to this little mistake

Comment: Is it possible to load the www folder reference from the server rather than keeping it locally ,so we have the regular updates.Is so,will it be possible to get the control over the native features like camera,calender in iphone.